# Jsoup, issue related conversion of '&gt;'

Tags: java, html, xml, jsoup

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data, "", Parser.xmlParser());

Where, data = "<p><script>$j('#DName').text($j('.someDropdown .NavtextOuter > span').text());</script></p>"
```

I'm getting output of **doc.html();** ==>

```
<p><script>$j('#DName').text($j('.someDropdown .NavtextOuter &gt; span').text());</script></p>
```

its not **converting back `&gt; to ">"`**

.And I must use xmlparser and .html();

I want the same output as data defined above. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to unescape entities in the result of html() method:

```
String data = "<p><script>$j('#DName').text($j('.someDropdown .NavtextOuter > span').text());</script></p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(data, "", Parser.xmlParser());
String content = doc.html();
String unescaped = Parser.unescapeEntities(content, true);
System.out.println(unescaped);
```

Comment: It kinda solved my issue. But any suggestion on how to unescape some fragment of data, means for particular element. Like, I want to unescape only script tag data and not the others'.

Comment: Jsoup method html() performs escaping automatically and according to original question description you have to use it.